# Remove parent if child contains text (in cdata)

Tags: xslt

I would like to remove parent  if child node value contains a specific text:

```
<SHOP>
    <SHOPITEM>
        <NAME>TEST 1 </NAME>
        <MANUFACTURER>
            <![CDATA[Apple]]>
        </MANUFACTURER>
    </SHOPITEM>
    <SHOPITEM>
        <NAME>TEST 2 </NAME>
        <MANUFACTURER>
           <![CDATA[Samsung]]>
        </MANUFACTURER>
    </SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```

I am using following XSLT code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


 <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM[MANUFACTURER = 'Samsung']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This code works if matching input is not in CDATA, but in the example code above not working, because manufacturer is in CDATA. Is there any trick to make it work?

Comment: The problem might be that `MANUFACTER` string value isn't just `'Samsung'` because it has leading and trailing white space characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="SHOPITEM[normalize-space(MANUFACTURER) = 'Samsung']"/>
```

---

P.S. This has nothing to do with CDATA. You will get the same problem with the input being:

```
<SHOP>
    <SHOPITEM>
        <NAME>TEST 1 </NAME>
        <MANUFACTURER>
            Apple
        </MANUFACTURER>
    </SHOPITEM>
    <SHOPITEM>
        <NAME>TEST 2 </NAME>
        <MANUFACTURER>
           Samsung
        </MANUFACTURER>
    </SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```